# Datatool: File ended while scanning use of \@dtl@next

Tags: datatool

I am trying to operator on a CSV file on a row-by-row basis with the following dummy code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
x,y
-10,2.43653438865896e-13
-9.59183673469388,4.78477532813286e-12
-9.18367346938776,7.9563926658023e-11
-8.77551020408163,1.12012542586698e-09
-8.36734693877551,1.33501414606147e-08
-7.95918367346939,1.34698479017595e-07
-7.55102040816327,1.15051489663322e-06
-7.14285714285714,8.31902240126465e-06
-6.73469387755102,5.09215716998077e-05
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    \DTLloaddb{table}{data.csv} 
    %
    \DTLforeach*{table}{%
        \xx=x,%
        \yy=y,%
    }{}%
\end{document}%
```

Which gives me

> File ended while scanning use of \@dtl@next.

What is wrong with this code?

P.S.: I am using lualatex on TL2018.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a spurious comma at the end of the second argument of `\DTLforeach`:

```
\DTLforeach*{table}{%
    \xx=x,%
    \yy=y,% <-- here
}{}%
```

(Empty elements aren't skipped by the parser.) Just remove it:

```
\DTLforeach*{table}{%
    \xx=x,%
    \yy=y%
}{}%
```

Comment: Ohh dear....I have wasted hours on that! You've got eagle eyes ;-) Thanks so much.